# Drawing a sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

Am kind of new to sequence diagrams and am a bit confused with sequence diagrams. I have a system where an administrator will manage the system, so my problem is if i am drawing a sequence diagram for my system , should i show the administrator interacting with all the features in the system ?
For example i have only shown administrator interacting with registering a new patient feature  only , but there are other features as well such as managing records , register new doctors , so should i show the interaction with those features as well ? Or only the main features ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You first need to have your use case diagram. Once you have that, you pick a use case and draw the sequence diagrams to represent how the system behaves for every action the user does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UML is not Bible. Feel free while using it.

If your diagrams get complicated, then show different aspects at different  diagrams.
And this is generally better.

So it is OKEY to show "register new doctor" and "manage records" in different sequence diagrams.

There is no obligation such that you have to show everthing in a single diagram.And for each diagram you should also not have to show "everthing". It is okey to filter unnecessary details: to prefer not to show them based on modeler view. Because **UML is just a visual thinking and communication tool.**